# cURL command failure

Tags: command-line, curl, batch-file

I am attempting to use curl commands in a batch file I am writing. I have downloaded the latest curl executable and run it but I cannot use the command "curl" What steps  should I take to use it correctly? The Command line still says

**"curl is not recognized as an internal or external command, able program or batch file"**

I am not interested in doing anything else with cURL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to add the directory containing `curl.exe` to your `path`, probably the `bin` directory.
In Windows XP you can do this by:

1. Right click your computer and choose properties
2. Click the advanced tab
3. Click environmental variables
4. Find `path` in the list and add the path to your curl directory

Comment: you mean the curl directory to the path?

Comment: Yes, the directory in wich you installed curl. Here is my path for example: `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32\wbem;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\bin;C:\libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc;` as you can see I have added both `mysql` and `curl` to my path so I can access these command directly from the commandline without standing in their specific directory.

Comment: Note, that each directory in the `path` is separated with a `;` character.

Comment: You can also have a look at this link: http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to install curl in windows**

**Install cURL on Windows**

There are 4 steps to follow to get cURL installed on Windows.

Step 1 and Step 2 is to install SSL library.
Step 3 is to install cURL.
Step 4 is to install a recent certificate

**Step One: Install Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables**

[Download Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables.](http://microsoft-visual-2008-redist.en.lo4d.com/)

**Step Two: Install Win(32/64) OpenSSL v1.0.0k Light**

Also from http://www.shininglightpro.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
For 64bit systems
Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.0k Light
For 32bit systems
Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0k Light

**Step Three: Install cURL**

Depending on if your system is 32 or 64 bit, download the corresponding** curl.exe.**
For example, go to the Win64 - Generic section and download the Win64 binary with SSL support **(the one where SSL is not crossed out)**.
Visit http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
**More specific Link:** http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win64-ssl-sspi

**Copy curl.exe to C:\Windows\System32**

**Step Four: Install Recent  Certificates**

Do not skip this step.
Download a recent copy of valid CERT files from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
Copy it to the same folder as you placed curl.exe (C:\Windows\System32) and rename it as **curl-ca-bundle.crt**

**If you have already installed `curl` or after doing the above steps, add the directory where it's installed to the windows path:**

1 - From the Desktop, right-click **My Computer** and click **Properties**.
2 - Click **Advanced System Settings** .
3 - In the System Properties window click the **Environment Variables** button.
4 - Select **Path** and click **Edit**.
5 - Append **;c:\path to curl directory** at the end.
5 - Click **OK**.
6 - **Close** and **re-open** the **command prompt**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its not on your path - try opening a new console window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to the path environment variable. If you want to do it through batch then you can update the reg key it stores the directories in with curl.exe like this:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "curlpath\curl.exe";%path%" /f
```

Or if the exe isn't dependent on any other files you could copy it to of paths existing directories like `C:\Windows\system32.`

Hope this helps!