# TeamCity error 'tscon.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: teamcity

I'm using tscon.exe to unlock a remote machine locally before I can run automation tests. When I run my command via RDC it works as expected and unlocks the remote machine locally:

**C:>tscon.exe %sessionname% /dest:console**

But I need this to run as my first TeamCity build step. Doing so either as a direct TeamCity Custom Script or starting a .bat file, both return the error:

**[16:50:22][Step 1/11] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\e4249c2d6a4e9e8d
[16:50:22][Step 1/11] 'tscon.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**

Why is tscon.exe not recognised when used via TeamCity?

Comment: tscon.exe exists in %windir%\System32\. Have you checked on your build agent whether tscon.exe exists or not.

Comment: tscon.exe does exist in %windir%\System32\ and that's why it is working when I run my command via RDC.

Comment: Try setting working directory to %windir%\System32\

Comment: It turns out that TeamCity cannot run an exe from within the %windir%\System32\ location (security reasons I imagine). Once I moved tscon.exe to another location, the build step worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had same issue and moving the exe out of System32 is not an option for me.So I have to dig deeper.

Turns out the problem is not Teamcity. It's windows.

"The windows filesystem redirection forces 32-bit application attempts to be installed into or accessed from %windir%\System32, been intercepted and get redirected or re-pointed to %windir%\SysWOW64 instead."

The solution is to use an alias name ( **%windir%\Sysnative** )  for that directory which windows will not redirected.

Try this :

```
 C:\Windows\Sysnative\tscon.exe %sessionname% /dest:console
```

For more detailed Reference :  http://www.tipandtrick.net/how-to-suppress-and-bypass-system32-file-system-redirect-to-syswow64-folder-with-sysnative/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

- Copy tscon.exe to any location other than %windir%\System32\
- i.e. C:\TeamCity\tscon.exe
- Add TC build step as below (ensure to include Working Dir):

[image]

- Now the remote machine will login locally before completing the TC steps