# curl is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: curl

C:\Users\WaQas>curl -v google.com

I have curl downloaded from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win32&flav=-&ver=2000/XP) and installed it following this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710748/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console).

I tested it with Command Prompt as this below

```
C:\Users\xxx>curl -v google.com
```

But I get an error message printed in the Command Prompt,

```
`curl` is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

Any idea what else should I do to make it work or what have I missed?

Comment: It could be the case that you have to add the curl command to your local path in Windows. Maybe `C:\path-to-curl-executable -v google.com` will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you probably do not have the path set. Set the environment path (add curl executable bin to the path) and then restart the command prompt. it should work

Comment: it is set automatically as `C:\Program Files\cURL\bin` if i follow the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611192/curl-command-failure

Comment: i unzipped the curl library i can't seem to find any executable .,

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43306905/6295712

try these solutions

**Method 1:**\

add "C:\Program Files\cURL\bin" path into system variables Path
right-click My Computer and click Properties >advanced > Environment Variables 
[image]

**Method 2:** (if method 1 not work then)

simple open command prompt with "run as administrator"