# Curl not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, cmd, hockeyapp

I have installed `curl` and have set it as `environment variable` in my system. But when running the `curl` command its giving an error `'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`I tried restarting my system but is of no use.I want this to upload my application to `HockeyApp`. Please help me out.I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: I know the question sounds to be a duplicated one.But I tried out almost all solutions given like adding the directory where it's installed to the windows path etc. But it's not working for me.

Comment: What happens when you call curl with its full path?

Comment: @SomethingDark: It's giving : curl: <6> could not resolve host :C

Comment: @SomethingDark:I am using hockey app api for uploading an android apk. Sorry for the incoorect typing format. -F and -H is not recognized
'curl \
  -F "status=2" \
  -F "notify=2" \
  -F "ipa=@android.apk" \
  -H "X-HockeyAppToken:TOKEN" \
  https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/APP_ID/app_versions/upload'

Comment: Are you replacing `APP_ID` with your API key? Also, I'm not positive, but I believe that you don't need the `\\` characters in the curl command.

Comment: @SomethingDark: APP_ID with app id of that particualr app and Token with the API token. " \ "character is a part of that API.I tried the same in  command line of mac and its working.But in Windows???

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you might need to escape the \ characters by preceding them with a ^

Comment: @SomethingDark: It's still not working..Anyway thanks for your time

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**Steps to install curl in windows**

**Install cURL on Windows**

There are 4 steps to follow to get cURL installed on Windows.

Step 1 and Step 2 is to install SSL library.
Step 3 is to install cURL.
Step 4 is to install a recent certificate

**Step One: Install Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables**

From https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=29
For 64bit systems
Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables (x64)
For 32bit systems
Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables (x32)

**Step Two: Install Win(32/64) OpenSSL v1.0.0k Light**

From http://www.shininglightpro.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
For 64bit systems
Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.0k Light
For 32bit systems
Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0k Light

**Step Three: Install cURL**

Depending on if your system is 32 or 64 bit, download the corresponding** curl.exe.**
For example, go to the Win64 - Generic section and download the Win64 binary with SSL support **(the one where SSL is not crossed out)**.
Visit http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

**Copy curl.exe to C:\Windows\System32**

**Step Four: Install Recent  Certificates**

Do not skip this step.
Download a recent copy of valid CERT files from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
Copy it to the same folder as you placed curl.exe (C:\Windows\System32) and rename it as **curl-ca-bundle.crt**

**If you have already installed `curl` or after doing the above steps, add the directory where it's installed to the windows path:**

1 - From the Desktop, right-click **My Computer** and click **Properties**.
2 - Click **Advanced System Settings** .
3 - In the System Properties window click the **Environment Variables** button.
4 - Select **Path** and click **Edit**.
5 - Append **;c:\path to curl directory** at the end.
5 - Click **OK**.
6 - **Close** and **re-open** the **command prompt**

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Nevin. I couldn't find the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables in step 1, but must have them install anyway as the remaining steps worked.

Comment: Like Paul, I wasn't able to find the item in `step 1` but it worked correct! Thanks for the detailed guide, +1

Comment: Great Post! Worked just fine. For Step Four, that link opens up as a bunch of text. I just copied pasted that into a text file and then changed the name to curl-ca-bundle.crt  -- you may need to have enable file extensions on to change the file extension.

Comment: Wait, your notes say to copy the EXE, not the source directory... so when you say "Append ;c:\path to curl directory at the end." this is very confusing because there is no curl "directory". Very confusing.

Comment: Same as above in windows 10 curl is already there in system32/curl.exe  then how should we configure it in Environment variable.

Answer (score 9):

**Here you can find the direct download link for Curl.exe**

I was looking for the download process of **Curl** and every where they said copy **curl.exe file in System32** but they haven't provided the direct link but after digging little more I Got it. so here it is enjoy, find **curl.exe** easily in **bin folder** just

> unzip it and then go to bin folder there you get exe file

[link to download curl generic](https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win64&flav=-&ver=*&cpu=x86_64)

Comment: In curl-7.53.1 there is no bin folder, rather you can find it here: `src/curl.exe`

Comment: find in src/ folder but not executed .

Comment: Thanks a lot.. After copy and paste, i started terminal from that path and it worked

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1:**\

add "C:\Program Files\cURL\bin" path into system variables Path
right-click My Computer and click Properties >advanced > Environment Variables 
[image]

**Method 2:** (if method 1 not work then)

simple open command prompt with "run as administrator"