# How to fetch files from remote host over SSH/SCP in Team Services build step

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, scp

With the build step "Copy files over SSH" in Team Services, it is possible to define an SSH endpoint and copy files to that host.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh

Now I want to fetch the files using the same SSH endpoint in Team Services.
How can I do that?

Comment: Problem solved. 
Solution (but not so nice): 
pscp.exe was added to the repo. VSTS could then use the build step "command line" to execute scp operations, both from and to the VSTS host.

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can add command line task to build defintion to call [curl](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-scpsftp.html) command to get file over SSH. If you are using on-premise build agent, you could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736666/curl-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batc) thread to install curl in windows.

Another way (if you are familiar with typescript), based on the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/CopyFilesOverSSH/copyfilesoverssh.ts#L119) of copyfilesoverssh, it gets necessary information of SSH (e.g. username, password), then based on that information to connect to SSH server and upload files.

```
var sshEndpoint = tl.getInput('sshEndpoint', true); 
  var username:string = tl.getEndpointAuthorizationParameter(sshEndpoint, 'username', false); 
  var password:string = tl.getEndpointAuthorizationParameter(sshEndpoint, 'password', true); //passphrase is optional 
  var privateKey:string = tl.getEndpointDataParameter(sshEndpoint, 'privateKey', true); //private key is optional, password can be used for connecting 
  var hostname:string = tl.getEndpointDataParameter(sshEndpoint, 'host', false); 
  var port:string = tl.getEndpointDataParameter(sshEndpoint, 'port', true);
```

Also, based on [this](https://github.com/spmjs/node-scp2) article’s sample, it can download file from server.

```
client.scp('admin:password@example.com:/home/admin/file.txt', './', function(err) {
})
```

So, you could refer to those code to build a custom build task to achieve download files from remote host over SSH/SCP.

Articles about add build task to VSTS: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task and http://blog.devmatter.com/custom-build-tasks-in-vso/