# libcurl-4.dll is missing after installing curl on Windows 7

Tags: windows, curl, dll, cmd, windows-7-x64

After installing curl as per this guy's [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28757477/1186038) :

*Except for Step 2: Installed **Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1u Light** instead since version k is missing from the download page : http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html*

On cmd prompt I just type :

```
C:\Windows\system32>curl
```

and get this error:

[image: error]

How do I get curl working on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

After extracting the Zip file to a specific location.
You should add the file location to the PATH Environment.

Unfortunately, you would also have to copy all the dll file from the lib folder and paste in the folder that contains the executable.