# Installation of Curl in windows environment

Tags: windows, curl, dll, web-api-testing

I am facing problem while installing curl in windows environment.

I have followed the steps mentioned in [Curl not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736666/curl-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batc/28757477#28757477)

We are using **curl-7.50.3**, downloaded form curl website. We have moved the required files to

> **C:/windows/systems32 folder**
>
> - Curl.exe
> - libcurl-4.dll
> - libcurl.dll.a

I am getting the same error where **libcurl-4-dll** files in not being found. [libcurl-4.dll is missing after installing curl on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168124/libcurl-4-dll-is-missing-after-installing-curl-on-windows-7)

> [Curl Error for missing libcurl-4-dll file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbZ3D.jpg)

We had made changes to the environment variables as suggested in [How do I install/set up and use cURL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-windows)

> Additionally, the latest version of curl offered on the websites, do
>   not seem to have Curl.exe files in them. Below the download link to
>   all curl versions
>
> https://curl.haxx.se/download/

Is there something that we are missing out, while installing and configuring Curl in windows ?

Comment: can you test this from cmd line and tell me if it works `set "curl=c:\windows\system32\curl.exe"` and then from the same cmdline type `curl` and press enter.

Comment: I tried and it is giving the same error of libcurl-4.dll file is missing

Comment: perhaps register the dll file

Comment: registering the dll file in the environment is not an option.

Comment: There are environment constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `git`, those files are available under directory: `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` in windows. Just copy all those error throwing `.dll` files and paste it inside: `C:\Windows\System32` directory.

**Warning:** Do not override any files if it asks for replacement.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Download the .exe file from https://cygwin.com/install.html for cygwin (a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows). 
Run the .exe file.
After finishing the installation click on the cygwin to open the curl console on windows and work on curl commands.