# Node.js Facebook Messenger bot curl not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, curl, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to create a facebook bot but can not connect to facebook because my node.js command prompt is telling me that "curl" is not recognized as an internal or external command. I have tried to download cURL and have followed the steps in this thread ([Curl not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736666/curl-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batc)) but the error still persists.

Here is a screenshot of the terminal:
[Curl Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffchA.png)

Answer (score 0):

cURL is a command line tool. The examples in the documentation are meant to give you a simple command line example for making the HTTP request. In node, you would want to use something like the request or restify module.

Comment: I got the same error when I used request instead of curl. Do you mind providing the exact wording I should use?

Comment: Request is a module that sends HTTP requests from node apps. cURL is a command line tool, so you can't just take the example are drop it into request. You need to do `request.post()` and include the url and body of the request, which are a part of the cURL request in the example. https://github.com/request/request