# curl can not start because brotlidec.dll is missing

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

I am very new for curl and I don't know much about curl.

I copied the files of curl downloaded from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32) to install the curl on win64. I followed each step mentioned in the [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736666/curl-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batc). After following every instruction when I tried to start the curl by typing `curl` in command prompt, I got the error saying that,

> The program can't start because brotlidec.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

I checked for the missing file in the directory and that file was there,then also it is showing this error.

Actually I am a diploma student and don't have much knowledge of it and I am installing curl for the IBM Watson text-to-speech API which i want to use it in a web page.

Can someone please help me to solve this issue. Any help will be accepted.
Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Vaibhav M.

Comment: Which one of the WIN64 downloads did you download and install?

Comment: @JustinPearce I downloaded zip file of win32 version.