# I am facing an error while installing paf

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

Error found in the command prompt

> curl is not recognized

while installing paf. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is curl installed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736666/curl-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batc ?

Answer (score 0):

we need to connect with the technical team for windows update. PAF installer only supports windows 10 version.